# SSL & JQuery = No Padlock / Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, ssl, authentication

Can somebody please explain to me where I am going wrong?

When I load my secure login page on `https://mydomain.com/login`, my padlock doesn't show. I played around for a while and found out when I removed the `<script src="http://mydomain.com/includes/jquery.js">` include the padlock came back.

What is wrong with JQuery and SSL together? Cos I really need to use JQuery on this particular page...

Comment: Is it `<script src="../../includes/jquery.js">`, or an absolute path?

Comment: Sorry I mage a mistake, yes the problem is when the include is from an absolute path. I corrected my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change it to:

```
<script src="https://mydomain.com/includes/jquery.js">
```

---

If you serve your assets (css/js/images) from a non-secure domain, you will lose the padlock.

It might even get worse. Your user might see this security prompt:

[image]

So ***please*** be sure to serve all your assets from your `https://...` domain.

Comment: So the reason my CSS attachment is allowed is because it's src="../../css/default.css"

Comment: Correct. If you use a (scheme) relative path, it'll automatically use the `https` version of it...

Comment: @Martin G.: Yes. I prefer to use only domain-relative URLs (`/css/default.css`) so I don't have to worry about domain or protocol changes. Another interesting and less known type of URL is the scheme-relative URL `//domain.com/file.css`, which uses the same scheme (http or https) as the current page.

Comment: I think I have decided to use https on every page by using a redirect when they hit my site...